# AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens' when importing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pyparsing, httplib2

I'm getting the follow dependency error when attempting to import tensorflow on a jupyter notebook:
`AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens'`

### The full error message is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-456b3b208783> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>
     46 from tensorflow.python import data
     47 from tensorflow.python import distribute
---> 48 from tensorflow.python import keras
     49 from tensorflow.python.feature_column import feature_column_lib as feature_column
     50 from tensorflow.python.layers import layers

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py in <module>
     25 
     26 # See b/110718070#comment18 for more details about this import.
---> 27 from tensorflow.python.keras import models
     28 
     29 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer import Input

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/models.py in <module>
     22 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
     23 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
---> 24 from tensorflow.python.keras import metrics as metrics_module
     25 from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizer_v1
     26 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py in <module>
     38 from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_spec
     39 from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer
     41 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import base_layer_utils
     42 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import keras_tensor

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in <module>
     58 from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import node as node_module
     59 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import autocast_variable
---> 60 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale_optimizer
     61 from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision import policy
     62 from tensorflow.python.keras.saving.saved_model import layer_serialization

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/mixed_precision/loss_scale_optimizer.py in <module>
     18 from __future__ import print_function
     19 
---> 20 from tensorflow.python.distribute import collective_all_reduce_strategy
     21 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribution_strategy_context
     22 from tensorflow.python.distribute import mirrored_strategy

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/collective_all_reduce_strategy.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.python.distribute import distribute_utils
     34 from tensorflow.python.distribute import input_lib
---> 35 from tensorflow.python.distribute import mirrored_strategy
     36 from tensorflow.python.distribute import multi_worker_util
     37 from tensorflow.python.distribute import numpy_dataset

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/mirrored_strategy.py in <module>
     32 from tensorflow.python.distribute import reduce_util
     33 from tensorflow.python.distribute import values
---> 34 from tensorflow.python.distribute.cluster_resolver import TFConfigClusterResolver
     35 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     36 from tensorflow.python.eager import tape

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/__init__.py in <module>
     29 from tensorflow.python.distribute.cluster_resolver.cluster_resolver import SimpleClusterResolver
     30 from tensorflow.python.distribute.cluster_resolver.cluster_resolver import UnionClusterResolver
---> 31 from tensorflow.python.distribute.cluster_resolver.gce_cluster_resolver import GCEClusterResolver
     32 from tensorflow.python.distribute.cluster_resolver.kubernetes_cluster_resolver import KubernetesClusterResolver
     33 from tensorflow.python.distribute.cluster_resolver.slurm_cluster_resolver import SlurmClusterResolver

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/gce_cluster_resolver.py in <module>
     26 _GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_INSTALLED = True
     27 try:
---> 28   from googleapiclient import discovery  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
     29   from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
     30 except ImportError:

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py in <module>
     46 
     47 # Third-party imports
---> 48 import httplib2
     49 import uritemplate
     50 import google.api_core.client_options

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in <module>
     50     # idea is to have soft-dependency on any compatible module called socks
     51     from . import socks
---> 52 from . import auth
     53 from .error import *
     54 from .iri2uri import iri2uri

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/httplib2/auth.py in <module>
     18 
     19 quoted_string = pp.dblQuotedString.copy().setName("quoted-string").setParseAction(unquote)
---> 20 auth_param_name = token.copy().setName("auth-param-name").addParseAction(pp.downcaseTokens)
     21 auth_param = auth_param_name + pp.Suppress("=") + (quoted_string | token)
     22 params = pp.Dict(pp.delimitedList(pp.Group(auth_param)))

AttributeError: module 'pyparsing' has no attribute 'downcaseTokens'
```

The AttributeError appears when attempting to import httplib2, which is dependent on a deprecated function in pyparsing.

```
!pip install httplib2
!pip install --force-reinstall -v "pyparsing==2.4.2"

import pyparsing as pyparse 

!pip show pyparsing 
!pip show httplib2 

import httplib2 as pp
```

I've tried importing an older version of pyparsing, but still drops the same error message.

Comment: The error you're experiencing seems to be related to an incompatibility between the pyparsing and httplib2 libraries. Try to update both libraries and try to install specific versions of both libraries. If you have no success check out the TensorFlow compatibility.

Comment: You are in conflict with the version of pyparsing being used by httplib2. The error message shows that pyparsing doesn't have the attribute downcaseTokens, which suggests that the version being used might be incompatible with the httplib2 library. 


Try to reinstall pyparsing :- !pip install --force-reinstall -v "pyparsing==2.4.2"


Make sure that you have the latest version of httplib2 installed.